# Failed to send data by http request to Autodesk tandem using Arduino IDE and node mcu

Tags: arduino, esp8266, autodesk-tandem

How to update the code below in order to send data to my digital twin stream on Autodesk Tandem by http request using arduino ide?

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

const char* ssid = "xxxxx";
const char* password = "xxxxxxx";

const char* clientID = "xxx";
const char* clientSecret = "xxx";
const char* modelID = "urn:adsk.dtt:zy-xxx";

const char* server = "tandem.autodesk.com";
const int port = 443;

String authToken = "Basic xxx=";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);

  // Connect to Wi-Fi
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
}

void postData() {
  // Construct payload
  const char* payload = "[{\"Temperature (C)\":25,\"id\":\"AQAAADKPYIggIUAVsiHJqUxjjNEAAAAA\"}]";

  // Post data to Tandem
  String path = "/api/v1/timeseries/models/" + String(modelID) + "/webhooks/generic?access_token=" + authToken;
  HTTPClient http;
  http.begin("https://" + String(server) + path);
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

  int httpCode = http.POST(payload);
  if (httpCode == 200) {
    Serial.println("Data sent successfully");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Failed to send data");
  }

  // Print HTTP response code and body
  Serial.print("HTTP Code: ");
  Serial.println(httpCode);
  Serial.print("Response: ");
  Serial.println(http.getString());

  http.end();
}

void loop() {
  postData();

  delay(60000);  // Wait for a minute before sending data again
}
```

i need to understand the issue that makes code fails to send data, and how to update it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your request doesn't include authentication. Use following steps:

1. In Tandem UI navigate to Streams then ... menu, then select Webhook Integration.
2. Copy value for Authorization token.
3. Use this for Authorization header:

```
http.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic xxx"); // this is value obtained in step #2 above
```

As alternative to Basic authentication is possible to use OAuth token provided by [APS Authentication service](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/overview/). In this case the token needs to be have access to facility (`data:write` scope). When using 2-Legged Authentication the service needs to be added to the facility.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your help, but it still gives me "Failed to send data
HTTP Code: -1" any other suggestions to fix this?

Comment: @rahmamo Can you check out if HTTP communication from your device works ok, pls? Is there more details available?

Comment: would you recommend a method to check if HTTP is working on my device. I am a beginner and it is really confusing to me. Regarding the details available besides auth token, I have the webhook endpoint. It is (/api/v1/timeseries/models/urn:adsk.dtm:zy-7WBr9SlOsHTZzF_NEug/webhooks/generic).

Comment: Try to call any REST service to see if you get response - i.e. use one of free weather APIs or so.